# what is 'property' in ruby programming language

Tags: ruby

I have a very basic question about Ruby which I can't seem to answer from browsing online:

`property :currency, String`

What does 'property' above mean? What circumstances should I use it under?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055378/whats-the-nature-of-property-in-a-ruby-class

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/DataMapper/Property

Comment: It's not a general Ruby thing - it's provided by some library you're using.

Comment: Isn't it like `attr_accessor` but with type-safety?

Answer (score 0):

As for many case in Rails, this is (most probably) a carefully disguised method call. Remember that in Ruby, parenthesis around method calls are options, so:

```
add(3, 4)
add 3, 4
```

are equivalent. So in your case,

```
property :currency, String
```

can actually be written as:

```
property(:currency, String)
```

So, a call to a method called "property" which takes two arguments, a Symbol and a Class. The method is most probably defined on a class from a library you are using.

Comment: thank for clarifying martin. It's indeed a method, but as defined by the second link provided by Bibek Sharma above.

Answer (score 0):

`property :currency, String` is a method call. When you find a line like that in a class then that means that a method `property` is called with `:currency` and `String` as parameter.

For the special mean of this method, look at [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/datamapper/dm-core/DataMapper/Property)